# Conflicting dependencies with google services (classroom) in android studio?

Tags: java, android, gradle, dependencies, google-play-services

I am trying to make an app that can connect to google classroom, read and display the data from it.

I am having a problem with dependencies.

the problematic dependency is :

```
implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-classroom:v1-rev135-1.23.0'
```

it seems that specifically google guava is a causing problems, i have tried excluding it but my imports wont work without it.

the error i get when trying to build is too long to list here, but essentially google guava is conflicting with something\itself, I've tried excluding it or importing it separately but nothing has worked.

i am trying to import:

```
import com.google.api.services.classroom.Classroom;
import com.google.api.services.classroom.ClassroomScopes;
import com.google.api.services.classroom.model.Course;
```

the full list of my dependencies is:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.7.0'
implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-classroom:v1-rev135-1.23.0'
implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.43.3'
implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:1.43.3'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
```

and the imports are:

```
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential;
import com.google.api.services.classroom.Classroom;
import com.google.api.services.classroom.ClassroomScopes;
import com.google.api.services.classroom.model.Course;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http.AndroidHttp;
```